# How to prevent modification of inherited properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I added some extra stuff to the standard wpf combobox. In the constructor I set two properties:

```
public SmartComboBox()
            : base()
        {
            this.IsEditable = true;
            this.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
            ...
        }
```

The two properties are inherited from System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox.
How do I prevent the modification of these two properties after I set their values in the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fully prevent it, the closest you can come is re-declaring the properties as new

```
public SmartComboBox()
{
    base.IsEditable = true;
    base.IsTextSearchEnabled = false;
    ...
}

public new bool IsEditable { get { return base.IsEditable; } }
public new bool IsTextSearchEnabled { get { return base.IsTextSearchEnabled; } }
```

The downside to this is that new is not an override, if the object is cast as its parent then the property can be set.

The other option is to wrap the class as Tigran mentioned, however the pita with that is exposing all the other properties you need.

Comment: The problem here is that there are a *lot* of occasions where the item is likely to be treated as a `Control`, rather than the derived type, and those properties are on `Control`, not `ComboBox`.  Thus it's rather likely that the base class' properties will be accessed, not the shadow properties.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned that as a downside to this approach. It only works where you have full control over the use of the class.

Comment: And my point is that in this case he won't.  In the general case it may be an option, and it may very well be an option in other contexts, but here it's clearly not a valid option as it relies on assumptions we know are false.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: you can't, as that properties modifiers can not be changed by you. 
If you want to hide an implementation, just *encapsulate*  `ComboBox` class inside your class.

```
public class SmartComboBox {

     private ComboBox _uiCombo = ....
}
```

And also in addition another thing yet:

In your example, in the code presented, there is no any reason of explicitly calling `base()` on `ctor`, as it will be called by `CLR`

Answer (score 1):

What if you override the metadata for the IsEditableProperty and play with PropertyChangedCallBack and CorceValueCallBack? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597491.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If `IsEditable` is marked as virtual, it should be trivial to just do

```
bool iseditableSet=false;
override bool IsEditable
{
    get;
    set
    {
      if(!iseditableSet){
        iseditableSet=true;
        base.IsEditable=value;
      }else{
        throw Exception...
    }     
}
```

If it's not marked as virtual, it's harder, but you can use "hiding" to prevent at least your own code from modifying the property without a very explict `base.` directive.. Of course, this is physically impossible to do though if you are dealing with a function that takes `Combobox` and it could possibly modify those properties. Just take it as a lesson why properties should almost always be virtual

Comment: It's not virtual (I just checked), and since it's likely to be modified by methods accessing it as a `Control` rather than as the derived type, they're not likely to see the shadowed version of the property, so this isn't really an option.